# Find next free hour given array of busy times

Tags: node.js, algorithm, date, google-calendar-api, momentjs

When using Google Calendar API, it takes:

`start` (epoch time) 
`end` (epoch time)
`timeZone` (i.e. `America/Los_Angeles`)

The response is an array called `busy` which contains objects like `{ start <Date>, end<Date>}`

My goal: find the next free hour between `start` and `end`.

with the following constraints:

- must be in workdays (Monday-Friday)
- must be in work hours (9am-5pm)

This is what I've tried:

1. manually create more `busy` objects for each day from 9am to 5pm
2. manually create more `busy` objects for Saturday and Sunday
3. merge all `busy` blocks together so there will be no intersection

now take the opposite times which are the `free` times.

The first free time object (`{start <Date>,end <Date>}`) for which `start`-`end` >= `1 hour`

is the next free hour. If none of the `free` objects is greater than 1 hour, there isn't a free hour between `start` and `end`

---

This sound too much for this problem, I'd like to hear suggestions

---

This is my code so far (working):

```
const moment=require('moment-timezone');
const chrono = require('chrono-node');
const ms = require('ms');
        /**
       * given start and end dates and list of busy dates, return the next free hour
       * @param {Number} start - epoch date
       * @param {Number} end - epoch date
       * @param {String} timeZone - to get the actual date data (like day of week for the start,end dates)
       * @param {Array} epochBusyRanges - [{start,end},{start,end}...] all epoch dates
       * @return {Number|null} if number, this is the start of the next available free hour
       */
      function nextAvailableHour(start, end, timeZone, epochBusyRanges) {


        //SOME SETTINGS
        const minMeetingTimeMS     = ms('1 hour');
        const startWorkDayAM       = 9;
        const endWorkDayPM         = 5;
        const weekendStartDateTime = 'friday 23:59';
        const weekendEndDateTime   = 'sunday 23:59';
        //manually put "busy" hours (work days (Monday to Friday) + work hours (9 to 17) are free,else busy)
        const momentStart          = moment.tz(start, timeZone);
        const momentEnd            = moment.tz(end, timeZone);
        let next5pm                = moment.tz(chrono.parseDate(`${endWorkDayPM}pm`, momentStart), timeZone);
        let next9am;
        while (Number(next5pm) < Number(momentEnd)) {
          next9am = moment.tz(chrono.parseDate(`tomorrow ${startWorkDayAM}am`, next5pm), timeZone);
          epochBusyRanges.push({start: Number(next5pm), end: Number(next9am)});
          next5pm = moment.tz(chrono.parseDate(`${endWorkDayPM}pm`, next9am), timeZone);
        }
        //we need to put also yesterday's 5pm-9am is the start is before 9am, otherwise it will make a "false" free time..
        if (momentStart.hour() < startWorkDayAM) {
          const yesterday5pm = moment.tz(chrono.parseDate(`yesterday ${endWorkDayPM}pm`, momentStart), timeZone);
          const today9am     = moment.tz(chrono.parseDate(`tomorrow ${startWorkDayAM}am`, yesterday5pm), timeZone);
          epochBusyRanges.push({start: Number(yesterday5pm), end: Number(today9am)});
        }
        //insert weekends manually
        let nextWeekendStart = moment.tz(chrono.parseDate(`this ${weekendStartDateTime}`, momentStart), timeZone);
        let nextWeekendEnd;
        while (Number(nextWeekendStart) < Number(momentEnd)) {
          nextWeekendEnd = moment.tz(chrono.parseDate(`next ${weekendEndDateTime}`, nextWeekendStart), timeZone);
          epochBusyRanges.push({start: Number(nextWeekendStart), end: Number(nextWeekendEnd)});
          nextWeekendStart = moment.tz(chrono.parseDate(`this ${weekendStartDateTime}`, nextWeekendEnd), timeZone);
        }
        //we need also last weekend if we happen to be inside it.
        if (momentStart.day() === 0 || momentStart.day() === 6) {
          const lastWeekendStart = moment.tz(chrono.parseDate(weekendStartDateTime, momentStart), timeZone);
          const lastWeekendEnd   = moment.tz(chrono.parseDate(`next ${weekendEndDateTime}`, lastWeekendStart), timeZone);
          epochBusyRanges.push({start: Number(lastWeekendStart), end: Number(lastWeekendEnd)});

        }
        //sort the times
        epochBusyRanges.sort((o1, o2) => o1.start > o2.start);
        //merge busy blocks
        epochBusyRanges = merge(epochBusyRanges.map(o => [o.start, o.end]));
        //map again to our format
        epochBusyRanges = epochBusyRanges.map(o => {return {start: o[0], end: o[1]}});
        //find next hour
        for (let i = 0; i < epochBusyRanges.length; i++) {
          const _start = i === 0 ? start : epochBusyRanges[i - 1].end;
          const _end   = epochBusyRanges[i].start;
          if ((_end - _start) >= minMeetingTimeMS) {
            return _start;
          }
        }
        //maybe there is a free time after the last busy block
        if (epochBusyRanges.length > 0) {
          const _start = epochBusyRanges[epochBusyRanges.length - 1].end;
          if ((end - _start) >= minMeetingTimeMS) {
            return _start
          }
        }
        //not busy time at all. so just check for the duration between start and end
        if (epochBusyRanges.length === 0) {
          if ((end - start) >= minMeetingTimeMS) {
            return start;
          }
        }
        return null;
      }


 //helper function: given [[10,20],[12,30],[40,50]] --- > [[10,30],[40,50]]
function merge(arr) {
          // copy and sort the array
          const result = arr.slice().sort((a, b) => a[0] > b[0]);
          let i        = 0;
          while (i < result.length - 1) {
            const current = result[i],
                  next    = result[i + 1];
            // check if there is an overlapping
            if (current[1] >= next[0]) {
              current[1] = Math.max(current[1], next[1]);
              // remove next
              result.splice(i + 1, 1);
            } else {
              // move to next
              i++;
            }
          }
          return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It usually isn't easy to work with timestamps or ranges and you're trying to do both.

That being said, you might be able to simplify your logic with [`moment-range`](https://github.com/rotaready/moment-range). It supports basic arithmetics (add, subtract, overlaps, intersections, ...) and iteration.

Comment: Thanks, given the arithmetics available, can you provide rough steps of the algorithm?